# Do we have any Group box in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, groupbox

In one of my application we need a group box like feature just like as shown in the picture below, We are using Twitter Bootstrap 3 css. I have searched whether there is any feature like that in Bootstrap 3 but couldn't find any, I don't know whether I am missing any, for the time been I have created my own css for creating a structure like that, but seems not that good.

Can anyone please tell me any component like this available in Bootstrap 3

**CSS**

```
table {
    border-collapse:separate;
    border:solid #2e6da4 1px;
    border-radius:6px;
    -moz-border-radius:6px;
}

td, th {

    border-left:solid #2e6da4 1px;
    border-top:solid #2e6da4 1px;
}

th {
    background-color: #337ab7;
    border-top: none;
}

td:first-child {
     border-left: none;
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ht0evtvx/)**

[image]

Comment: You can just use col-md-3 4 times in a row to have 4 'groupboxes'

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/6752/ like this

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels

Comment: @K.B.M yes exactly ...but can we have other colors for the title

Comment: @AlexMan You can always customize the colors using CSS to override the default, or use the standard color schemes built-in to bootstrap. Take a peek at the examples that come with bootstrap when you download it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try panels from bootstrap: **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/6752/)**

HTML:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">Panel heading without title</div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    Panel content blah <br/>blah <br/>blah <br/>blah <br/>blah <br/>blah <br/>blah <br/>blah <br/>blah <br/>blahblah <br/>blah <br/>blah <br/>blah <br/>blah <br/>blah <br/>blah <br/>blah <br/>blah <br/>blah
  </div>
</div>
```

Yes you can: **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/6753/)**

Use `panel-primary` for Blue color. For more info **[Reference Link](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panel-title)**

```
<div class="panel panel-default">...</div>
<div class="panel panel-primary">...</div>
<div class="panel panel-success">...</div>
<div class="panel panel-info">...</div>
<div class="panel panel-warning">...</div>
<div class="panel panel-danger">...</div>
```

Comment: Panels is the way to go !!

Answer (score 2):

Use panels from Bootstrap: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/11045/)**

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">Panel heading without title</div>
        <div class="panel-body">Panel content blah
            <br/>blah
            <br/>blah
            <br/>blah
            <br/>blah
            <br/>blah
            <br/>blah
            <br/>blah
            <br/>blah
            <br/>blahblah
            <br/>blah
            <br/>blah
            <br/>blah
            <br/>blah
            <br/>blah
            <br/>blah
            <br/>blah
            <br/>blah
            <br/>blah</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In Bootstrap 4, panel has been replaced by card.  See [Migrating to V4 .panel to .card](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/migration/#panels)

Full info here: [Bootstrap’s cards](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/card/)

Answer (score 1):

There is something almost exactly this in the base bootstrap examples.
http://getbootstrap.com/examples/theme/

They call them "panels" Here's the code:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
    </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
             Panel content
        </div>
</div>
```